# Why is my Meteor app's greater than ($gt) count different than mongdb shell's?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Here is my input and output in the mongodb shell:

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.users.count({"profile.score": {$gt: 50}})
2
```

Here is my code:

```
var allUsers = Meteor.users.find();
var newCurrentRank = allUsers.count({"profile.score": {$gt: 50}});
console.log("newCurrentRank", newCurrentRank);
```

Here is my console:

```
I20161004-11:43:42.910(0)? newCurrentRank 12
```

Comment: There are a total of 12 users in the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the **[`count()`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/minimongo/minimongo.js#L216)** method in Meteor returns the number of documents from a cursor that match a query. In itself passing a query as argument will not affect the count. Hence in your example above it was returning all the 12 documents despite passing the query object as argument, the count is based on the [**`find()`**](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-find) cursor which is returning all the documents in the collection since it was called without any query.

What you need is to call the [**`find()`**](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-find) cursor with the query object and then call the **[`count()`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-count)** method:

```
var newCurrentRank = Meteor.users.find({ "profile.score": { "$gt": 50 } }).count();
console.log("newCurrentRank", newCurrentRank);
```